# How to tell which row is chosen by GROUP BY in a SELECT statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table called `products`:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ productID ║ designID ║ isFeatured ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 111111111 ║ AAAAA    ║ 0          ║
║ 222222222 ║ AAAAA    ║ 1          ║
║ 333333333 ║ AAAAA    ║ 0          ║
║ 444444444 ║ BBBBB    ║ 0          ║
║ 555555555 ║ BBBBB    ║ 0          ║
║ 666666666 ║ CCCCC    ║ 0          ║
║ 777777777 ║ DDDDD    ║ 0          ║
║ 888888888 ║ DDDDD    ║ 0          ║
║ 999999999 ║ DDDDD    ║ 1          ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

The column `isFeatured` (BOOL) can have the value `1` or `0`. (And only one `isFeatured` per `designID` row could be `1`, all others will be `0`. Or there could also be all `isFeatured` be `0` per `designID`.)

Now I want to filter my results from table in a way that only one row for every `designID` is shown but if it has a `isFeatured = 1` this row should be choosen. In other cases it won't matter at all. Like this:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ productID ║ designID ║ isFeatured ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 222222222 ║ AAAAA    ║ 1          ║
║ 444444444 ║ BBBBB    ║ 0          ║
║ 666666666 ║ CCCCC    ║ 0          ║
║ 999999999 ║ DDDDD    ║ 1          ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

But no matter what I try I always get the same results by using `GROUP BY`.

First I tried it by this statement:

```
   SELECT designID, productID, isFeatured
     FROM products 
 GROUP BY designID 
 ORDER BY isFeatured DESC, designID ASC
```

And I got sth. like this:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ productID ║ designID ║ isFeatured ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 111111111 ║ AAAAA    ║ 0          ║
║ 444444444 ║ BBBBB    ║ 0          ║
║ 666666666 ║ CCCCC    ║ 0          ║
║ 777777777 ║ DDDDD    ║ 0          ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

This won't work because the sorting happens after the grouping. Okay, I understand so far.

After searching for a while I came up with this try:

```
SELECT designID, productID, isFeatured
  FROM ( 
      SELECT * 
        FROM products 
    ORDER BY isFeatured DESC 
) sub 
GROUP BY designID 
ORDER BY isFeatured DESC, designID ASC
```

Which gives me the exact results like before. But I don't understand why because it's doing the grouping on another set of rows (with different order) ??

So my questions are:

1. Why is it not working by my second statement?
2. What is the correct statement to get the results like intended?

Thanks!

Comment: The manual explains all this at some length

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibiloty

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products  (
>   `productID` INTEGER,
>   `designID` VARCHAR(5),
>   `isFeatured` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO products 
>   (`productID`, `designID`, `isFeatured`)
> VALUES
>   ('111111111', 'AAAAA', '0'),
>   ('222222222', 'AAAAA', '1'),
>   ('333333333', 'AAAAA', '0'),
>   ('444444444', 'BBBBB', '0'),
>   ('555555555', 'BBBBB', '0'),
>   ('666666666', 'CCCCC', '0'),
>   ('777777777', 'DDDDD', '0'),
>   ('888888888', 'DDDDD', '0'),
>   ('999999999', 'DDDDD', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT productID,designID,isFeatured 
> FROM products
> WHERE isFeatured = 1
> UNION
> SELECT MIN(productID),designID,isFeatured
> FROM products
> WHERE designID NOT IN (SELECT designID FROM products WHERE isFeatured = 1)
> GROUP BY designID,isFeatured
> ```
>
> ```
> productID | designID | isFeatured
> --------: | :------- | ---------:
> 222222222 | AAAAA    |          1
> 999999999 | DDDDD    |          1
> 444444444 | BBBBB    |          0
> 666666666 | CCCCC    |          0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>     FiRST_VALUE(productID) OVER (
>         PARTITION BY designID
>         ORDER BY isFeatured DESC
>     ) productID,
>     `designID`
>     ,FiRST_VALUE(isFeatured) OVER (
>         PARTITION BY designID
>         ORDER BY isFeatured DESC
>     ) isFeatured
> FROM
>     products
> ```

> ```
> productID | designID | isFeatured
> --------: | :------- | ---------:
> 222222222 | AAAAA    |          1
> 444444444 | BBBBB    |          0
> 666666666 | CCCCC    |          0
> 999999999 | DDDDD    |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86b8cfc02c741c978f5ef5ca11ad77d0)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Your second statement gives right answer under `MySQL 5.5` and `5.6`. However, it gives wrong answer under `MySQL 5.7` and `8.0`. In fact, `MySQL 5.7` and `8.0` prevents `GROUP BY` with not functionally dependent columns and we need to disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in `sql_mode` to force run the statement. I'm guessing the underlying code for `GROUP BY` in `MySQL 5.7` and `8.0` doesn't cover the issue here.
2. The result could be fixed in `MySQL 5.7` and `8.0` by simply moving out the subquery to another table.

```
CREATE TABLE sub AS SELECT * 
    FROM products 
    ORDER BY isFeatured DESC;

SELECT productID, designID, isFeatured
--  FROM ( 
--      SELECT * 
--        FROM products 
--    ORDER BY isFeatured DESC 
-- ) sub
FROM sub 
GROUP BY designID 
ORDER BY isFeatured DESC, designID ASC;
```

```
productID   designID  isFeatured
======================
222222222   AAAAA   1
999999999   DDDDD   1
444444444   BBBBB   0
666666666   CCCCC   0
```